# Related to simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am trying to understand how the equation (2) is obtained after simplifying equation (1).
\begin{align}
&&90 = \tan^{-1}(\omega T_1)+ \tan^{-1}(\omega T_2) \tag{1} \\
&&\tan^{-1}\biggl(\frac{\omega T_1 + \omega T_2}{1-\omega^2 T_1 T_2}\biggr) = 90 \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $T_1$, and $T_2$ are positive constants and $\omega$ denotes frequency.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If
$$
\alpha=\arctan(\omega T_1)\quad\text{and}\quad\beta=\arctan(\omega T_2),
$$
then
$$
\tan(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\tan(\alpha)+\tan(\beta)}{1-\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}=\frac{\omega T_1+\omega T_2}{1-\omega^2T_1T_2},
$$
and therefore
$$
90^\circ=\alpha+\beta=\arctan\left(\frac{\omega T_1+\omega T_2}{1-\omega^2T_1T_2}\right).
$$

Comment: Thank u sir for ur response....